# 11 Harry Potter rebus puzzles which together spell a word

Tags: word, cipher, visual, rebus, literature

11 Harry Potter rebus puzzles. When you have solved them all, there is a word they are hiding.

[image: Rebus puzzles]

Hint:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/arozR.jpg

Comment: Isn't the given hint same as the picture itself?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Not exactly.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, Sorry, just noticed the numbers on it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**COMPLETE SOLUTION**: The solutions to the 12 rebuses are as follows...

> 1. **The fat lady** (the guardian to Gryffindor Tower) *[LADY written in thick letters]*
>
>  2. **Age line** (a charm acting as a barrier which prevents people above or below a specific age accessing a specific area) *[a line of AGEs]* (found by @Annosz in comments)
>
>  3. **Unbreakable vow** (a strong promise, bonded by magic which if broken will result in death) *[the letters of VOW marked up with HTML non-breaking spaces]*
>
>  4. **Holyhead** (hometown of Quidditch team, the Holyhead Harpies) *[the word HEAD, full of holes (holey)]*
>
>  5. **Sorting hat** (the magical hat which decides which house each new Hogwarts student will belong in) *[the letters HAT, sorted differently]*
>
>  6. **Half-giant** (somebody who has one human parent and one parent who is a giant, like Rubeus Hagrid) *[the top half of the word 'GIANT']*
>
>  7. **Grindylow** (a magical creature) *[green D, low]*
>
>  8. **Pettigrew** (Peter Pettigrew, one of the four Marauders, later servant to Voldemort) *[increasing sizes of the word 'petty' - petty grew]*
>
>  9. **Lavender Brown** (a Gryffindor student in Harry's year) *[the word 'Brown' written in lavender colour]*
>
>  10. **“The cat’s among the pixies”** (idiom, the wizarding equivalent to "the cat's among the pigeons") *[tabby = cat; surrounded by many 'pixie's]*
>
>  11. **Exploding bonbons** (a popular wizarding sweet) *[4 'BON's can give us 2 'BONBON's, illustrated with blast shapes]*

Noting that:

> The border of each rebus has a number of gaps in it, we can count the number of gaps and index the discovered phrase using that number to find the letter of interest:
>
>  ELLDNIWGRAD
>
>  <sub>Th[E] fat lady
>
>  Age [L]ine
>
>  Unbreakab[L]e vow
>
>  Holyhea[D]
>
>  Sorti[N]g hat
>
>  Half-g[I]ant
>
>  Grindylo[W]
>
>  Petti[G]rew
>
>  Lavende[R] Brown
>
>  “The c[A]t’s among the pixies”
>
>  Explo[D]ing bonbons</sub>
>
>  Note that the image in the hint spoiler contains additional numbers which indicate the number of letters in each completed phrase, enabling us to be sure we have the correct letters for the solution.

This then anagrams to the final answer:

> **GRINDELWALD** - the wizard who features heavily in the *Fantastic Beasts* spin-off franchise, who has a complicated friendship and rivalry with Albus Dumbledore, headmaster of Hogwarts throughout Harry's time at the school.

Comment: The second one is rot13(ntr yvar (n punez hfrq gb cerirag crbcyr nobir be orybj n fcrpvsvrq ntr sebz npprffvat n fcrpvsvp bowrpg be cynpr). Vg lvryqf gur yrggre 'y'.)

Comment: @Annosz Of course! Book 4... Thanks, will add :)

Comment: All are correct. Just one left to solve.

Comment: Solved. Great job!