# Harry Potter Rebus Puzzles #2

Tags: word, wordplay, visual, rebus, literature

Here are 4 more Harry Potter word rebuses for you to solve!

[image]

(11 more Harry Potter rebuses are posted [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94415/11-harry-potter-rebus-puzzles-which-together-spell-a-word).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1

> "What in the name of Merlin?" (confirmed by OP)

## 2

> Aconite Fluid = AC on ITE (in fluid-gender colours?)

## 3

> Fenrir Greyback = fenrir written backwards in grey

## 4

> Gringotts = Green GOTs

Comment: All correct! To be most accurate, #1 is rot13(Jung va gur anzr bs Zreyva).