# Harry Potter Rebus Puzzles #3

Tags: word, wordplay, visual, rebus, literature

Another set of Harry Potter word rebuses for you to solve!

[image]

Part 1: [11 Harry Potter rebus puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94415/11-harry-potter-rebus-puzzles-which-together-spell-a-word)

Part 2: [Harry Potter Rebus Puzzles #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97520/harry-potter-rebus-puzzles-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These resolve to:

> **Witherwings** (the pseudonym of the hippogriff, Buckbeak) *[two 'WING'S, WITH 'ER']*;
>
>  **Divination** (the future-telling subject taught by Prof. Trelawney) *['DIV' IN 'ATION']*;
>
>  **Kings Cross** (the London railway station from where one can travel to Hogwarts) *[two famous KINGS making a CROSS shape]*; and
>
>  **London Underground** (because Dumbledore has a scar above his knee in the shape of the route map of the London Underground!) *['LONDON' UNDER 'GROUND']*